# How to upgrade python major version (e.g. 3.5 to 3.8) with all installed modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, upgrade

I've installed python  3.x two years ago.
I'd like to update to python 3.8.x, **and also update all included modules**.
99% of the modules were installed via pip (1-2 might've been installed via package manager).

- Is there a step-by-step guide?
- is there a script that bumps a full python version?

The only options I know right now are:

- remove python3.x and all its modules, and install the new version, and manually, selectively specify all modules with pip.
- create a list of current packages, and try to feed that list to pip install

Let's assume python3 is non-essential core O.S, no core component depends on python3 (let's take it as granted). Only my own scripts depend on specific python3 modules, and I handle them manually.

I'm *not* interested in multiple version, nor virtualenvs.

The question is relevant both to linux (ubuntu 16+) and windows (7+). This is not a production server - these have totally different procedure of installation via requirements.txt & setup scripts.

Comment: for the pip modules: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then (with `pip` of the new python interpreter) `pip install -r requirements.txt`? and: ubuntu heavily depends on the python installation! if you remove it you will break the installation.

Comment: There is no need to remove the old versions. This should also hint that there is no prepackaged solution which does this.